# Does Single Sign on work for Facebook on Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I attempted single sign on with Facebook on android about 6 months ago and it was not working. Today, I try again and I'm still getting "invalid_key"

My steps:

1. Create keystore
2. Create KEY-SIGNATURE as per (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)

   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
   | openssl sha1 -binary
   | openssl base64
3. Submit KEY-SIGNATURE to developer site for my app

Has nothing changed????

Comment: what platform are you trying this on? try leaving out the openssl pipes and see that the exportcert is actually working.  Its possible that you are generating a hash with the fail message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had issues with the key generation under windows. i switched under linux and did the same process and it all went good and the key worked.. this happened also to some other devs i know so its a common thing. again the same exact process but under linux instead of windows (Both xp and windows 7)